# Convert std::basic_string<wchar_t> and std::basic_string<uint16_t>

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stl, wstring

In MacOS X 10.10 CLang:

```
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > string;
typedef basic_string<wchar_t, char_traits<wchar_t>, allocator<wchar_t> > wstring;
```

I build a string like:
std::wstringstream ss;

```
ss << "[";
ss << "{";
ss << "x1:" << 111 << ",";
ss << "z1:" << 111;
ss << "},";
ss << "{";
ss << "x2:" << 222 << ",";
ss << "z2:" << 222;
ss << "}";
ss << "]";
std::wstring str = ss.str();
```

and need to pass `str` as argument to a function that expects `std::basic_string<uint16_t>` and returns string of the same type.

How to do conversion between `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` and  `std::basic_string<uint16_t>` to make use of the external library function?

C++11 is allowed.

Maybe some use of `wstring_convert` or some workaround?

Comment: Have a look at / search for [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to be sure, that the source `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` has the same encoding as the input `std::basic_string<uint16_t>`. If the encoding is different you should look for a specific character encoding conversion algorithm. Otherwise you can do something like this.

```
std::basic_string<uint16_t> result;
std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
```

Comment: Din't work. `(27010,0x1029b7000) malloc: *** error for object 0x600000256bf0: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
`

Comment: try this std::back_inserter(result) instead